useReducer type definitions not working typescript
I am trying to implement a useReducer hook in TypeScript like so:
export interface ScannerState {
    showAction: boolean;
    data?: QRData;
}

export function mergeObjReducer<S extends object>(state: S, changes: Partial<S>): S {
    return { ...state, ...changes };
}

const [scannerState, setScannerState] = useReducer(
     mergeObjReducer,
     { data: undefined, showAction: false },
);

// here typescript doesn't provide me with suggestions of the keys of the object. 
setScannerState({data: "some data value"});

//expecting the above line to suggest me keys of data or showAction currently ts doesnt provide me with any suggestions. 

//and if i try to access a property of the useReducer state like so: 
const test = scannerState.showAction;

//i get the following error: Property 'showAction' does not exist on type 'object'.


How do I fix the type definitions so that TypeScript understands what all the keys are of the value that useReducer expects?

I just had to provide the generic type to my mergeObjReducer when defining the useReducer hook like so:
const [state, setState] = useReducer(
    mergeObjReducer<ScannerState>,
    { data: undefined, showAction: false },
);

